# How to add an additional employee to an office?

Tags: office-layout

We are seven in our office room. The company will be acquired by a larger company soon.

In order to buy new computers, the company should say how many people is in each office.

The office manager suddenly came into the office to say that a new table will be placed to add one more person.

What is the normal way to make that change?

Comment: Negatives votes? Say why please!

Comment: The office doesn't belong to you, it belongs to the company. They are free to use it as they see fit.

Comment: You're lucky. I am begging my boss to add another employee to my office. He says he can't afford it for now.

Comment: Is it a person on your team or just some guy? Is your room a team room?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the office manager, it's their responsibility to ensure the office space is used optimally and that everyone has a good space to work, stocked with the supplies they need. If they first go around and ask every employee what they would think then they are having someone else take their responsibility for them.

If you have concerns that the addition of an extra desk will detract from *your* ability to do *your work*, you can raise this with the office manager politely, but until you've actually experienced working in the new set-up for a while, you may want to hold off on that. There is a very large chance that you will be seen as 'one of those guys who is afraid of any change', which can lead to problems down the road.

Also remember to only speak for yourself, don't speak for your colleagues. You may think you have a stronger position if you speak for "the team" but at the same time, when you make a complaint you are raising a negative flag, which will reflect badly on you. Even if they agree with you, it's for your colleagues to decide if they feel strongly enough about the issue to raise this negative flag as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could discuss the matter with the other six people in the office. If this affects most or all of you, then the matter should be discussed. Otherwise you are looking for trouble.

Comment: How to set the overall group position. Democracy way?

Comment: @Biotechnologist Why you do feel the workplace should be a democracy?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Although the question was focused from the manager point of view, your answer is also useful for the current situation.

Comment: Well @Dan, I don't think the authoritative way is the best one from the employee point of view. Although I have to recognise that sometimes decisions are made thinking in the overall company gain. In theory, an office manager should have better company perspective than a standard worker.

Answer (score 1):

Employees are virtually never asked for their opinon on these things.  This is just the way the world works and you need to understand that they don't care that you don't want another person in your space. Whatever space they put this person into will have people who don't want him there. And even more people will object if he gets a private office that they think they should have gotten. Assigning space is a difficult and thankless task as there is only rarely a case when no one objects. This is one of the reason why some facilites managers love the concept where no desks are assigned and eveyone picks which one to pwrok in that day (which is frankly the worst of all worlds to almost everyone except the facility manager.)

The decision is based on several factors: similar type of work or need to work togther, physical room available, political pull of the managers involved; type of office space the company deems appropriate for the individual (a trainee is not going to get that empty corner office no matter what!).